# Close Connection when try connect to IP Camera (with Onvif URL) using AForge?

Tags: c#, aforge, onvif

I want connect using the library AForge.NET to an IP camera with ONVIF Device Service URI similar to this :

```
http://admin:admin@192.168.1.142/onvif/device_service
```

but send this error :

```
the underlying connection was closed: the connection was closed
unexpectedly
```

How can I work with the ONVIF protocol in AForge.NET?

Thank's

Comment: Are you sure that it's the correct URL to stream? What's your camera model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to the ONVIF Device Service, not the streaming URI. It's better for you to connect to the camepra with [ONVIF Device Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/). If I remeber correctly, when you request the live video, it shows the streaming URI for the video feed.

Answer (score 0):

Been a moment since the question were asked, but for the following person looking for an answer. add the following code to your app.config

```
<system.net>
<settings>
<servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
</settings>
</system.net>
```